# Dokuwiki: Wiki-Code and Wiki-Content on different drive?

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, wiki, nas, dokuwiki

I would like to install Dokuwiki on one drive(e.g. Raspberry SD-Card, NAS-Flash) and put the Wiki-Contents(Pages, Mediafiles,...) on a different drive.

Is there a good instruction how to do it?

Thank you very much,

Best Regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:savedir on how to configure where data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

This is the path where all DokuWiki files will be stored:

```
Type: String
Default: ./data
```

It may be an absolute path, or a path relative to the directory where the DokuWiki software is installed. It needs to be writable by the webserver!

> Warning: Changing this option could make your wiki and the configuration menu inaccessible!

See also the DokuWiki documentation about your question on https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:savedir.